# HFSS - Air box's (Radiation Boundary) dimensions change the results (that must not happen)

Tags: rf, antenna

I am designing a rectangular patch antenna and I am facing an issue that I don't know what should I do. I am trying to design an antenaa that will resonate inside of water box with some other substances that has dielectric constant of er=33. But I don't know how big the box must be and also why by changing the dimensions of the air box (radiation box) the results are also changing (the radiation box is always larger than λ/4 starting for the edges of the water box)?

The designers of HFSS Ansys say that this must not happen and that the dimensions of the radiation box must not affect the results (on condition that the dimensions are larger than λ/4).
Thank you in advance.

---

@ThePhoton thank you again for your help.
Let me describe again my problem:

1. I create a vacuum box
2. Right click --> Assign Boundary -->Radiation
3. When I change the dimensions of this vacuum box the S11 parameter changes

**Resonance frequency = 1 GHz**

At the beginning I was using "Fast" as a Sweep Type and when the dimensions of the vacuum box was increasing I had totally different results. I changed that to "Discrete" (that step was after my initial question on Stack Exchange, when I found this comment on a similar question on Ansys Forum) but again I got a bit different values. I am presenting 2 different simulations:

[image: my antenna]

[image: S11_100mm]

[image: S11_200mm]

*Setup parameters:*
Maximum number of passes: 30
Maximum Delta S: 0.01
Minimum converged passes: 2

Its 3dB difference but again I don't know why.

Comment: Does the Ansys documentation say that the box size *will* not affect the result, or that you must choose a box large enough so that it *does* not affect the result? I'm surprised if  \$\lambda/4\$ is large enough to be sure that it will not.

Comment: @ThePhoton it says that it needs to be large enough (more than λ/4). And in that case the results supposed that will not change.
Also I found those similar questions on ANSYS Forum but they couldn't totally answered them.

1. https://forum.ansys.com/forums/topic/simulation-results-changing-with-size-of-radiation-box/
2. https://forum.ansys.com/forums/topic/what-you-mean-by-radiation-box-in-hfss/
3. https://forum.ansys.com/forums/topi...n-box-size-in-hfss-if-we-have-two-antennas-2/

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Note: If I read the Ansys material correctly, it doesn't say the size of the box should be at least $\lambda/4$. It says the boundaries should be at least $\lambda/4$ away from the antenna. If the antenna is placed at the center of the box, that means the size of the box must be at least $\lambda/2$. From your description I can't tell for sure if you set up your model that way or not. (A diagram of the model and graphs showing how much the boundary is affecting the results might help us answer)

Comment: @Katerina - Hi, You wrote an "answer" but it was actually more info, not a solution, so it has been added to your question as an edit (i.e. an update) instead. || Since you asked the question, unless you are writing the *full & final* answer to your own question (i.e. you don't need further help & you solved the problem yourself using a different solution than any other answer) please don't use the box labeled "Your Answer" below. Instead, to add more info / clarification, please [edit] the question. Or *comment* to respond to an answer. || Please see the [tour] & [help] for more rules. Thanks

Comment: Please bear in mind that the numerical methods in HFSS and other solvers are not bullet proof and don’t apply to all conceivable physical configurations. For instance, some boundary condition implementations give non-physical results if you put a dielectric boundary on them, eg. an area with er=1 and another er>1. In your case, I would sweep the box size upwards with no dielectric present, and see when the results stabilise. Then check them against published results for a known patch antenna design.